# Is it possible to dismiss all toasts without animation?

Tags: reactjs, react-toastify

Based on react-toastify [docs](https://fkhadra.github.io/react-toastify/remove-toast/) consumer might call

```
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
...
toast.dismiss();
```

to dismiss all the opened toasts on the screen. They will follow the preconfigured animation.

The question is how to dismiss them immediately without the animation.

Answer (score 0):

does this help?

```js
toast.clearWaitingQueue();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't